# how to parse a string to a function name in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a function like following :

```
vm.saveStep = function(service, method, data, formData, steps){
      service.update({}, data).$promise.then(function (res) {
        if(formData != null) {
          fileUploadService.create({}, formData).$promise.then(function (res) {
            steps.step2 = true;
          }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log('Error uploading files');
          });
        }
      }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log('Error saving data');
      });
    };
```

in this function I have the `method` argument, this argument can take two different String values `'create'` and `'update'`.

Inside this function I call the `service.update()` or `service.create()` depending on the `method` argument value.

The issue is that I don't know how to parse that string value so when I pass `'create'` I call `service.create()` and when I pass `'update'` I call `service.update()`.

## Edit:

I forgot to mention that when I pass `'update'` I want to call `service.update({}, data)` and for `'create'` I want to call `service.create(data)`, notice `{}` in update function

what I mean my function will be like this :

```
vm.saveStep = function(service, method, formData, steps){ ..... }
```

and then when I pass `'create(data)'` as a string I'll call `service.create(data)` and for  `'update(data)'`  I'll call `service.update({}, data)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the bracket syntax:

```
service[method](arg1, arg2, ...);
```

Alternatively, if you need different arguments, you can just do an `if`-statement:

```
if(method === "create"){
    service.create(arg1, arg2);
}else if (method === "update"){
    service.update(arg1);
}
```

Comment: thanks, the first solution was what I wanted, but I forgot to mention something in my code please check my update.

Comment: Then you should probably use the second solution